# pandas.DataFrame.from_dict() inconsistent behavior with orient = 'index' option - is this a bug?

Tags: python, pandas

in pandas 1.5.0, this works:

```
import pandas as pd 

data1 = {
    2010 : {'width': 0.1, 'height' : 0.6},
    2011 : {'width': 0.2, 'height' : 0.7},
    2012 : {'width': 0.3, 'height' : 0.8},
    '2010-2012' : {'width': 0.2, 'height' : 0.7}
}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1, orient = 'index')
```

I expected the following to work as well, but it doesn't:

```
data2 = {
    2010 : {'width': 0.1},
    2011 : {'width': 0.2},
    2012 : {'width': 0.3},
    '2010-2012' : {'width': 0.2}
}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2, orient = 'index')
```

Apparently it tries to sort the index and throws a TypeError, because the last key of the dict is of type `str`, while the rest are `int`s:

```
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/api.py in union_indexes(indexes, sort)
    184         result = indexes[0]
    185         if isinstance(result, list):
--> 186             result = Index(sorted(result))
    187         return result
    188 

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I can achieve what I want with this workaround:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2).transpose()
```

But I'm curious whether there's a reason `from_dict()` tries to sort the index in the second case and not in the first one.